# DDEV not starting project after update to 1.10.2

Tags: macos, ddev

After updating Docker and DDEV to the newest versions it is not possible to start a project.
I have just updated DDEV from an older version to the newest one. Now it is not possible to start any old or new project.
I have tried already a tip (ddev config global --instrumentation-opt-in=false) that removes an error message from the end of the "DDEV config" but "DDEV start" always failed.

This is the output of "ddev version":

```
commit              v1.10.2
db                  drud/ddev-dbserver:v1.10.0-10.2
dba                 drud/phpmyadmin:v1.10.0
ddev-ssh-agent      drud/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.10.2
docker              19.03.1
docker-compose      1.24.1
os                  darwin
router              drud/ddev-router:v1.10.0
web                 drud/ddev-webserver:v1.10.2
```

This is how I can reproduce it:

```
cd test
ddev config
(pressing Enter to all question to use the default values)
ddev start
```

Instead of starting the container this error messages are outputted:

```
Building ddev-ssh-agent
[3674] Failed to execute script docker-compose
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 80, in _execute
  File "subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
  File "subprocess.py", line 438, in run
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-desktop', 'get']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 264, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 35, in get
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 93, in _execute
dockerpycreds.errors.StoreError: Credentials store docker-credential-desktop exited with "error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `no hostname in URL`".

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 127, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1085, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1081, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 527, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 344, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1084, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 260, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 307, in _set_auth_headers
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 304, in get_all_credentials
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 281, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-desktop exited with "error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `no hostname in URL`".',)
Failed to start test: failed to start ddev-ssh-agent: Failed to run docker-compose [-f /Users/michaeloehlhof/.ddev/ssh-auth-compose.yaml -p ddev-ssh-agent up --build --force-recreate -d], err='exit status 255', stdout='', stderr='Building ddev-ssh-agent
[3674] Failed to execute script docker-compose
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 80, in _execute
  File "subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
  File "subprocess.py", line 438, in run
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-desktop', 'get']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 264, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 35, in get
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 93, in _execute
dockerpycreds.errors.StoreError: Credentials store docker-credential-desktop exited with "error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `no hostname in URL`".

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 127, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1085, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1081, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 527, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 344, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1084, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 260, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 307, in _set_auth_headers
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 304, in get_all_credentials
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 281, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-desktop exited with "error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `no hostname in URL`".',)'
```

Comment: Can you share the config.yml file?

Comment: It does look like `docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-desktop exited with "error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `no hostname in URL`".',)'` is the problem. I don't think this is a ddev problem.

Comment: This is my config.yaml
`APIVersion: v1.10.2
name: test
type: php
docroot: ""
php_version: "7.2"
webserver_type: nginx-fpm
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
mariadb_version: "10.2"
nfs_mount_enabled: false
provider: default
use_dns_when_possible: true
timezone: ""`

Answer (score 2):

I got the error fixed, but don't know exactly what was the reason.
Untick the "Securely store docker logins in macOS keychain" doesn't helped, it leads to another error.
I have created a login for Docker Hub, error still exists.
In my OSxKeyChain there were multiple entries named with "Docker Credentials". I removed old entries and renamed some entries until there was only one Entry "Docker Credentials" wich has the data of my newly created Docker Hub account. Then I renamed the other entries back to "Docker Credentials" and it works. One of the old entries I have deleted must be the source of the problem.